# I'm trying to install ncmpcpp, but when installing boost it hangs here

Tags: osx, homebrew, boost

The following shows what happens when I try to install ncmpcpp (on OS X):

```
brew install ncmpcpp                                                                  !181
==> Installing dependencies for ncmpcpp: boost, taglib
==> Installing ncmpcpp dependency: boost
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.60.0/boost_1_60_0.tar.b
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-1.60.0.tar.bz2
==> Patching
patching file boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp
==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1
==> ./b2 headers
==> ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/li
```

I've left it for over two hours and nothing has changed.

Comment: Is it using the CPU?  Compiling boost can indeed take a long time.

Comment: I see the cpu usage ramps up to max then after about 20-30 minutes it goes back down to normal usage and then it just stays like that for the next hour and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

but I had it while running `brew upgrade` it

I cleaned up with `brew cleanup boost`
Then I `brew unlink boost`
Then `brew uninstall boost`
Further `brew cleanup ncmpcpp`
And `brew unlink ncmpcpp` - probably not needed for you
Then `brew uninstall ncmpcpp`
After in /Libraries/Caches/Homebrew I removed downloaded files for boost
And now I run `brew install --only-dependencies ncmpcpp`
And after that `brew install ncmpcpp`

And finished well in 10 minutes and I successfully continued with `brew upgrade`

P.S For some unknown to me reason when I tried to run `brew install boost` separately, before running above mentioned manipulations, it was downloading el_capitan.bottle tarball and then install **ncmpcpp** would download just usual boost tarball. Even though `brew install boost` has already installed boost from el_capitan.bottle tarball. From here I just run above mentioned procedures and all is good now.